# variance of partial covariance

Tags: variance, covariance, uncertainty

Consider three **non independent** random variables : $Z,Z_i,Z_j$, the partial covariance is given by:

$$pcov(Z_i,Z_j;Z)=cov(Z_i,Z_j)-\frac{cov(Z_i,Z)cov(Z_j,Z)}{var(Z)}$$

Suppose I know estimates of all the terms in this formula and estimates for $var(cov(Z_i,Z_j))$, $var(cov(Z_i,Z))$ ,$var(cov(Z,Z_j))$ and $var(var(Z))$, that is I know estimates for the uncertainty on all terms of the formula.

Is there a way to get **any kind** of global uncertainty on the partial covariance or is it wishful thinking ?

Thanks